# row-break feature like column-break in css

Tags: css, html

I have a series of divs inside a main div which is created dynamically and the result is like the following

```
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 200px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 400px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 900px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 100px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 200px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 300px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 20px"> </div>
  <div class="subdiv" style="width: 600px"> </div>
<div/>
```

I want to break a div if the total width exceeds the container's width.

**This**

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾container‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|                                                                      | 
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|   subdiv1    |       subdiv2      |       subdiv3                                    |
|______________|____________________|__________________________________________________|
|                                                                      | 
|                                                                      | 
|______________________________________________________________________|
```

**will become this:**

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾container‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|                                                                      | 
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|   subdiv1    |       subdiv2      |       subdiv3 - first part       |
|______________|____________________|__________________________________|
|                                                                      | 
|                                                                      | 
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|                                             | 
| subdiv3-remaining      |                                             | 
|________________________|                                             | 
|                                                                      | 
|______________________________________________________________________|
```

Using column-count and column-break property, you can do this but vertically.
Check my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CRzSP/2/).

I want to do this **horizontally**. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to maintain your column layout but have it wrap like rows?

Comment: Would `display: inline` be an option for your situation? ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/mSdMW/)) There are some drawbacks to that though.

Comment: Interesting but it works as I wanted. Thanks. Edit: wait! I don't have any text inside divs. Therefore It won't work :(

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do here, you cannot do it.

Comment: Well, I found a very nasty hack. I'll programatically assign space characters (`&nbsp;`) inside them. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mSdMW/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-div { overflow:hidden; }
.subdiv { float:left; }
```

Comment: I want to break a div into two if necessary. This doesn't.